# How can I cash out my prepaid cell phone?

Tags: united-states, savings, currency, cost-cutting, mobile-phone-plans

As a very frugal person, I have a prepaid phone plan that costs $100 a year. For the past two years, I've spent roughly $50 of that each year. As long as I renew the plan with another $100 every year, I can carry over the unused balance.

But there's a hitch; if I only used half of the balance one year, I'm not likely to vary that dramatically. I was talking with a friend of mine who had a Virgin prepaid plan and lamented that he had accrued quite a balance this way over a few years and decided it was a ripoff. I understand the sunk costs fallacy, though maybe not why he decided it was enough to change providers.

I'm comfortable with writing off 50 dollars a year, but I'm wondering if there's any good way to cash my balance out, or at least put it to a better cause than T-Mobile's bottom line. I hear about some places using [minutes as currency](http://www.mobilemoneysummit.com/) and I'm wondering: is there anything now or on the horizon in the US that might let me cash out the unused balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using T-mobile you don't have to put $100 in each year to keep your minutes for a year.  Once you spend $100 you get a year with any additional minutes you buy.  Buying them $100 at a time is the cheapest way - but when you renew you can renew with only $50 or $30 and you have a year to use them from the last time you bought.

I did this this year - only put $50 on each phone because we don't use $100 worth in a year.

Comment: Of course, the marginal rate is less attractive at 50 dollars.

Comment: harmanjd - Do you have a link to the T-mobile "plans" that offer the year expiry of credit (Can't seem to find this info on their website)? Also, does this/these "plan(s)" require the purchase of a new cellphone, or could an existing one be used?

Comment: T-Mobile has been juggling their prepaid plan definitions, so what's available today may be different from the legacy plans some of us are on.

Answer (score 2):

I've found you can give the money to charity.  If you text REDCROSS to 90999 for example you can give $10 to the redcross

Comment: +1, great suggestion. I had a prepaid phone with an excess balance, and this is what I did. Took a tax deduction for it as well. I found that I could only use a code a few times before it would quit working for me, so I had to choose several charities to get rid of the whole balance.

Answer (score 0):

I typically only purchase $10-$20 for each of our phones yearly as we do not use them very much.  The first year, I purchased $100 for each, but after that, any amount will continue service for a year and you keep/roll over any unused minutes.  Can't beat $$20-$60 per year for two phones...I just wish their coverage was much better in rural areas.  I wish Verizon offered the same deal as their coverage is superior in Ohio.